# Get request is not working from my Xamarin IOS app

Tags: api, xamarin, asp.net-web-api, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I have a button that I am using to test my API in Xamarin Forms running on my IOS device. The API completes get requests fine on Postman but returns null when I make the request from my iPhone.

I know the IP and Port are correct because I copy and pasted it straight from Postman.

```
public class API
{
    public const string apiUrl = "https://(IP ADDRESS):(PORT)/api/Properties";

    public async Task<List<PropertyModel>> GetPropertyModelAsync()
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/json");
        HttpRequestMessage requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, apiUrl);
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(requestMessage).ConfigureAwait(false);

        var propertyJsonString = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        var properties = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<PropertyModel>>(propertyJsonString);

        return properties;
    }
}`
```

I am not sure if the requests are being rejected or they are timing out.

Comment: If they timeout you will get an exception.  You need to check the response code to determine if the server was able to handle the request

Comment: If it works in Postman, then something in the setup in your app must be different, for example missing Authorization Headers, which are the root cause in many cases. What response do you get?

Comment: @ewerspej it works completely fine when I write the function out in the page however, when I try to call the function from another class it just stops working. I have no idea why this is.

Comment: Then perhaps show us the code where it works and the code where you say it doesn't. You may want to remove the `ConfigureAwait(false)`, which might be the culprit here. Also, you should `await` the call to `response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()` instead of accessing the `Result` which is a blocking call inside an asynchronous method, which is discouraged.